# multiple video streaming

Tags: opencv

I'm currently experimenting with video stream opencv. But,I think I can only stream one video at a time.Is it possible to stream multiple videos at the same time?If there are other packages that would be possible, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Not sure but either [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) or [MJPG-streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer) can do the job!